# Removing debug macros in Rust

Tags: logging, rust, rust-cargo

I'm writing an application that uses slog for logging multiple things during its execution. As such, I make extensive use of the `info!`, `error!`, `warn!` and `debug!` macros.

However, as expected, the `debug!` calls are there to help me debug the applications and I don't want those calls polluting the logs when actually using the application.

I've been trying to compile them away without success. This is the line I'm using: `RUSTFLAGS="$RUSTFLAGS -C debug-assertions" cargo build --release`

The compilation goes on smoothly, but on execution I see all the debug calls.

The following is a working example of my issue:

Cargo.toml:

```
[dependencies]
slog = { version = "1.5", features = ["max_level_trace", "release_max_level_warn"] }
slog-stream = "1.2.0"
slog-term = "1.5.0"
slog-json = "1.2.1"
slog-stdlog = "1.1.0"
log = "0.3.7"
```

main.rs:

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate slog;
extern crate slog_stream;
extern crate slog_term;
extern crate slog_json;
extern crate slog_stdlog;
#[macro_use]
extern crate log;

use std::path::Path;
use std::fs::OpenOptions;
use slog::DrainExt;

fn init_logger(work_dir : &Path) {
    let mut log_dir_buf = work_dir.to_path_buf();
    log_dir_buf.push("log");

    if !log_dir_buf.exists() {
        std::fs::create_dir(log_dir_buf.as_path()).unwrap();
    }

    log_dir_buf.push("the_log_file.log");
    let log_file_name = log_dir_buf.to_str().unwrap();

    let log_file = OpenOptions::new()
                        .create(true)
                        .write(true)
                        .truncate(true)
                        .open(log_file_name).unwrap();

    let console_drain = slog_term::streamer().build();
    let file_drain = slog_stream::stream(log_file, slog_json::default());
    let logger = slog::Logger::root(slog::duplicate(console_drain, file_drain).fuse(), o!());
    slog_stdlog::set_logger(logger).unwrap();
} 

fn main() {
    init_logger(Path::new("."));

    info!("This is an info message");
    warn!("This is a warn message");
    error!("This is an error message");
    debug!("This is a debug message");
}
```

Now, building a release version as stated above and running the binary I get the following output:

```
Jan 23 17:20:56.640 INFO This is an info message
Jan 23 17:20:56.641 WARN This is a warn message
Jan 23 17:20:56.641 ERRO This is an error message
Jan 23 17:20:56.641 DEBG This is a debug message
```

Finally, rust version:
`rustc 1.31.0 (abe02cefd 2018-12-04)`

I know the version of slog I'm using is old, but upgrading the dependency is not a priority at the moment. However, the [version's documentation](https://docs.rs/slog/1.5.0/slog/#notable-details) states that log filtering should be possible as @shepmaster describes in the [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34538397/is-it-possible-to-change-the-log-level-for-an-application-at-compile-time), it just doesn't seem to work for me. What am I missing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to change the log level for an application at compile time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34538397/is-it-possible-to-change-the-log-level-for-an-application-at-compile-time)

Comment: Thanks for the link @PeterHall. Tried the provided solution and it still doesn't work. Edited my question with further details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to simplify the issue, I made another working example with the current version of slog (2.4.1) that set a global scope logger and the issue *still* reproduced. This is the code example:

```
extern crate slog;
extern crate slog_async;
extern crate slog_json;
extern crate slog_term;
extern crate slog_scope;
extern crate slog_stdlog;
#[macro_use]
extern crate log;

fn complex_logging() -> Result<(), log::SetLoggerError> {
    //Create the output file
    let log_path = "your_log_file_path.log";
    let file = OpenOptions::new()
        .create(true)
        .write(true)
        .truncate(true)
        .open(log_path)
        .unwrap();

    //Create the terminal drain
    let decorator = slog_term::TermDecorator::new().build();
    let d1 = slog_term::FullFormat::new(decorator).build().fuse();
    let d1 = slog_async::Async::new(d1).build().fuse();

    //Create the file drain
    let d2 = slog_json::Json::new(file)
        .add_default_keys()
        .build()
        .fuse();
    let d2 = slog_async::Async::new(d2).build().fuse();

    //Fuse the drains and create the logger
    let logger = slog::Logger::root(slog::Duplicate::new(d1, d2).fuse(), o!());
    let _guard = slog_scope::set_global_logger(logger);

    //register slog_stdlog as the log handler with the log crate
    slog_stdlog::init().unwrap();


    trace!("logging a trace message");
    debug!("debug values \"x\" => 1, \"y\" => -1");
    info!("some interesting info; where => right here");
    warn!("be cautious!; why => you never know...");
    error!("wrong, foobar; type => unknown");

    Ok(())
}

fn main() {
  let _res = complex_logging();    
}
```

Running the above example after building for release yields this result:

```
Jan 30 13:53:52.398 TRCE logging a trace message
Jan 30 13:53:52.399 DEBG debug values "x" => 1, "y" => -1
Jan 30 13:53:52.399 INFO some interesting info; where => right here
Jan 30 13:53:52.399 WARN be cautious!; why => you never know...
Jan 30 13:53:52.399 ERRO wrong, foobar; type => unknown
```

However, a new example that passes loggers around fixes the issue. Here's the working example:

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate slog;
extern crate slog_async;
extern crate slog_json;
extern crate slog_term;
extern crate slog_scope;
extern crate slog_stdlog;

use slog::Drain;
use std::fs::OpenOptions;
use std::io;
use std::sync::Mutex;

fn duplicate_log() {
    let plain = slog_term::PlainSyncDecorator::new(std::io::stdout());
    let d1 = slog_term::FullFormat::new(plain).build().fuse();
    let d2 = Mutex::new(slog_json::Json::default(io::stdout())).fuse();
    let log = slog::Logger::root(slog::Duplicate::new(d1, d2).fuse(), o!("version" => env!("CARGO_PKG_VERSION")));

    trace!(log, "logging a trace message");
    debug!(log, "debug values"; "x" => 1, "y" => -1);
    info!(log, "some interesting info"; "where" => "right here");
    warn!(log, "be cautious!"; "why" => "you never know...");
    error!(log, "wrong {}", "foobar"; "type" => "unknown");
    crit!(log, "abandoning test");
}

fn main() {
   duplicate_log();
}
```

Running the working example yields the following result:

```
Jan 30 13:56:30.839 INFO some interesting info, where: right here, version: 0.1.0
{"msg":"some interesting info","level":"INFO","ts":"2019-01-30T13:56:30.839762+00:00","version":"0.1.0","where":"right here"}
Jan 30 13:56:30.839 WARN be cautious!, why: you never know..., version: 0.1.0
{"msg":"be cautious!","level":"WARN","ts":"2019-01-30T13:56:30.839787+00:00","version":"0.1.0","why":"you never know..."}
Jan 30 13:56:30.839 ERRO wrong foobar, type: unknown, version: 0.1.0
{"msg":"wrong foobar","level":"ERRO","ts":"2019-01-30T13:56:30.839802+00:00","version":"0.1.0","type":"unknown"}
Jan 30 13:56:30.839 CRIT abandoning test, version: 0.1.0
{"msg":"abandoning test","level":"CRIT","ts":"2019-01-30T13:56:30.839815+00:00","version":"0.1.0"}
```

If you are running into a similar issue as I did, **my problem was setting a global scope logger**. Passing around loggers fixes this issue.

Answer (score 1):

[This link](https://rust-lang.github.io/rustc-guide/compiler-debugging.html#how-to-keep-or-remove-debug-and-trace-calls-from-the-resulting-binary) might be helpful in your situation.

According to the documentation linked above,

> calls to `debug!` and `trace!` are only included in the program if `debug-assertions=yes` is turned on in **config.toml**

Have you checked your **config.toml** file to see if `debug-assertions` is set to yes?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think this is not helpful in this instance since it's the opposite of the behaviour I'm observing (I want the debug calls gone), and this guide is specific to contributing to the rustc compiler.

Comment: Indeed, `config.toml` is specific to rustc's build system.

Answer (score 1):

The `slog` crate [relies on the `debug-assertions`](https://docs.rs/slog/1.5.0/src/slog/lib.rs.html#773-808) codegen option to distinguish between "release" builds and "debug" builds. Thus, by enabling `debug-assertions` (by passing `-C debug-assertions` to the compiler via `RUSTFLAGS`), `slog` doesn't take the `release_max_level_*` feature flags into account.

`debug-assertions` are disabled by default in release builds, so if you didn't mean to enable `debug-assertions`, simply don't pass that flag to the compiler. Note also that you can enable or disable `debug-assertions` via the [`[profile.*]` sections](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html#the-profile-sections) in `Cargo.toml`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @Francis. I tried not passing the flag before as well, just `cargo build --release`. The `debug message` still shows.