# Is there a way to statically disable Rust logging in production builds of my application?

Tags: logging, rust

I have a WebAssembly module written in Rust that performs logging for debug purposes via the `log` crate during development.  I notice that, even when I don't configure a logger, the formatting and calls to internal `log` functions remain in the generated WebAssembly module.  This wastes bytes since the output of those functions will never be used/displayed.

Is there any way to statically disable logging without having to remove the log macro calls in the code?  Additionally, is there a way to only disable this in release builds?

Comment: It looks like your question might be answered by the answers of [Is it possible to change the log level for an application at compile time?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34538397/155423). If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: @shepmaster how do you always find these duplicates? I spent a good 10 minutes googling to even find the official docs for this feature. Do you have some secret or am I just bad at googling?

Comment: Oh, you wrote the answer...

Comment: In the hope that wasn't a rhetorical question, I have a Firefox bookmark that turns `r foo` into `https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com rust foo`. In this case, `foo` was `log feature`. While there are some answers that I remember, it's not every one, not even my own.

Answer (score 10):

Yes; the `log` crate provides [features flags](https://docs.rs/log/0.4.8/log/#compile-time-filters) that allow logging to be statically disabled at compile time up to a certain level.

If you want to completely disable all logging in release builds but keep normal logging in debug builds, change your entry in `Cargo.toml` to include the `release_max_level_off` feature like this:

```
log = { version = "0.4", features = ["release_max_level_off"] }
```

This will cause all calls to logging functions to be eliminated from the resulting binary, taking any related formatting code with it via dead code elimination.